# При наведении на ссылку появляется background-color,но текст прыгает.Нужно сделать так чтобы текст оставался на месте

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #313030;
    height: 88px;
}


.nav__inner {
    display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
    margin-right: 60px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__link:hover {
    background-color: red;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav__inner">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">home</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">portfolio</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">about us</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">contact</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На ховере размеры трогать не надо. ;)

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #313030;
    height: 88px;
}


.nav__inner {
    display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
    margin-right: 60px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
    background-color: red;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav__inner">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">home</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">portfolio</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">about us</a>
            <a class="nav__link" href="#">contact</a>
   </div>
</div>
```